# MariaDB installation is showing random letters

Tags: debian, mariadb

So I want to setup MariaDB with nginx and I have in the past but for some reason on my debian 7 machine the MariaDB is all glitched out and shows random letters. Any idea why?
Thanks

http://prntscr.com/59g61n

Comment: I'm not too sure on a solution - I can only think think your system is missing a fonts package. Typing will still work correctly and doesn't affect the installation. I still have this problem and still haven't found a remedy.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing at all to do with MariaDB itself.

The configuration interface is trying to draw boxes around the text but the line drawing characters aren't interpreted correctly by your terminal program. This means that there is a discrepancy between what character set should be used and what is actually being used, and/or the terminal type is not quite correct.

You could just ignore those and continue to configure MariaDB etc., this is just a cosmetic problem as this point.

Otherwise you'd have to find out what terminal type your terminal program is emulating, and what yur Debian system thinks you're using (`echo $TERM`). If you're using `putty` then you may need to change settings under the "translation" menu (the "translation" is about how characters are translated).

Answer (score 0):

Change encoding to UTF-8 for the terminal you are using.
As wurtel said :

> The configuration interface is trying to draw boxes around the text but the line drawing characters aren't interpreted correctly by your terminal program